# Service not logging to journalctl

Tags: systemd, journald, journalctl

I have a user service which is placed under `/home/<user>/.config/systemd/user/<service>.service`

When I perform `systemctl --user status <service>` I have the desired output, for example:

```
<user>@<server>:~$ systemctl --user status <service>
● <service>.service - Service
     Loaded: loaded (/home/<user>/.config/systemd/user/<service>.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-07-27 10:23:34 UTC; 9min ago
   Main PID: 19059 (<service>)
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1008.slice/user@1008.service/<service>.service
             └─19059 /home/<user>/.local/share/<software>/install/active_release/bin/<software>-validator

Logs
Logs
Logs
```

But when trying to see the full logs with `journalctl --user -u <service> -f` I can't see anything, the output is the following:

```
<user>@<server>:~$ journalctl --user -u <service> -f
No journal files were found.
```

I have this setup running in a lot of other servers with exactly the same configuration, but this happens only in this one which is some servers from Equinix, maybe there is some different configuration for journalctl in this provider? But it's important to point out that I have installed other services in this machine (not users ones, but system-wide) and it haven't happened.

/etc/systemd/journal.conf is in its default configuration.

I have seen this post slightly related with my problem: [Linux journalctl not synced with systemctl status / Journalctl not updating](https://serverfault.com/questions/993332/linux-journalctl-not-synced-with-systemctl-status-journalctl-not-updating), I tried to insert `StandardOutput=journal` and `StandardError=journal` under the [Service] section, did `systemctl --user daemon-reload` and restarted the service but I can't see any logs in journalctl yet.

I also checked my /var to validate if it couldn't be lack of disk space, but I have quite a lot of space free in my disk.

My service is configured like this now:

```
[Unit]
Description=<Service description>
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1

EnvironmentFile=/home/<user>/rpc.env

ExecStart=/home/<user>/bin/<service_script>.sh

#ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/taskset -a -p -c 5-23 28-47 $MAINPID
CPUAffinity=5-23 28-47

Nice=-10


LimitNOFILE=700000
LimitNPROC=700000

LogRateLimitIntervalSec=0
LogRateLimitBurst=0

WorkingDirectory=/home/<user>/

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Do you guys have any ideia how I can fix it?

Comment: The correct syntax is `journalctl --user-unit <name>.service ...`

Comment: Yeah, that worked perfectly. But I always used the syntax `journalctl --user -u <service> -f` and it still work in my other servers.

Probably these nodes came with all latest packages, and in a new version of systemd the syntax above may be deprecated. The correct one is indeed `journalctl --user-unit <name>.service`

Thank you

Comment: Had exactly the same issue, the answer here in the comments should be an actual answer and accepted